# Estimation Question - London Eye

Tags: estimation

Good afternoon, I was recently at an assessment center and was asked an estimation question. This was the first one I've ever done so was wondering how everybody else would go about solving the problem.

I had 10 seconds to look at the attached photo, and then I was asked to calculate the mass of the London eye, I had 10 minutes to provide an answer.

Would somebody be able to do the same question and explain the methods?

Comment: There is no photo attached

Comment: The website has said I don't have enough reputation to post images...

Comment: add an url.., though https://en.wikiarquitectura.com/index.php/London_Eye provides an answer already

Comment: @Pieter21 I don't see any estimation based on a picture on that site?

Comment: This is a link to a picture similar to the one I was given.                                  https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/90/f0/75/90f075fa0c32991034a67ba17a458be5.jpg

Comment: @obsi, how did you approach, and what was your answer?

Comment: @pieter21 thank you for your answer it will help me a lot when trying to learn how to answer questions like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not about providing an exact answer, but about your approach to handling such problems:

http://www.caseinterview.com/estimation-question-tips

So estimate the height (let's say 100m, though in fact it is 135). Making the circumference 316m.

From it's shape, I'd say that the circumference and 2 poles totaling about 184 meters contribute most to the weight. So we have 500m..

I would estimate that about each meter, you'd need the weight equivalent of a reasonably big car for the construction, so I'd say 500m * 1500 kg = 750 tons.

For construction, an engine that has to be placed somewhere, and inner parts, I'd round this up to 1000-1250 ton.

Actual answer is 2100 ton, but I think this is well within reasonable estimation range.

Comment: as it was my first assessment center ever and first time approaching a question like this I wasn't really sure what to do, I initially calculated the volume of the carts, the wheel and the struts and then added them together, I knew how much 1m cubed weighs so multiplied the number I got with the weight of 1m cubed. I believe I ended up around 600 tonnes which I knew was well off the mark I was just looking for how one should have treated the situation